# Tomcat not starting after modifying a xml file

Tags: java, tomcat8

I modified the *web.xml* file from a dynamic web project in Eclipse EE and now I can't start the Tomcat server. 
Error shows:

> Server Tomcat v8.0 Server at localhost failed to start.

and in the console:

> SEVERE: Failed to destroy end point associated with ProtocolHandler ["ajp-nio-8009"]

How can i fix this ?

Comment: Grammetical correction and formatting.

Answer (score 0):

The service is already running on port 8009. You should kill it and try tomcat restart.

Answer (score 0):

Try this :
Terminate the tomcat, restart it from **command prompt** and then first undeploy and then redeploy your web application.